# Cron php with codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, cron, stripe-payments

I don't have code but I have question for subscription payments. 
I use stripe library for subscription and my questions how to make update different users on platform e-commerce for to know if users subscriptions are expired or not? 
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Stripe webhooks for that:

https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks

It would let you set up an endpoint where Stripe would send you events happening in your account. In your case you'd want to look at `invoice.payment_failed` or `customer.subscription.updated` to know when a subscription status becomes `past_due`. Or even `customer.subscription.deleted` when all the payment retries failed.

Comment: Thanks, I want to try this

Comment: So, I don't use Cron Job on webserver but webhooks of stripe.

Answer (score 0):

my code code with subscription stripe

```
public function checkout(){
        $userid = $this->session->userdata('userid');
        $email = $this->input->post('email');
        $token = $this->input->post('stripeToken');
        try {

            $customer = \Stripe\Customer::create(array(
                "email" => $email,
                "source" => $token,
                "description" => "Abonnement"
            ));

            $subscription = \Stripe\Subscription::create(array(
                "customer" => $customer->id,
                "plan" => "premium",
            ));

            $invoice = \Stripe\Invoiceitem::create(array(
                  "customer" => $customer->id,
                  "amount" => 2000,
                  "currency" => "eur",
                  "description" => "Abonnement",
            ));

             // data captured
            $data = array(
                'id_user' => $userid ,
                'prix_abon' => 20,
                'date_abon' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
                'date_suspension' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
                'etat_abon' => 1,
                'subscribe_id' => $subscription->id,
                'customer_id' => $customer->id

            );
            $response = $this->md_abonnement->add($data);
            if ($response) {
                $this->sms .= "$.Notification.autoHideNotify('custom', 'top right', 'Abonnement effectué')";
                $this->session->set_userdata('controller_message', $this->sms);
                redirect($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'],"refresh");
                print_r($customer->id);
                print_r($subscription->id);
            } else {
                $this->sms .= "$.Notification.autoHideNotify('error', 'top right', 'Une erreur est survenu durant votre abonnement', 'Veuillez bien vérifier vos informations')";
                $this->session->set_userdata('controller_message', $this->sms);
                redirect($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'],"refresh");
            }

        } catch (Stripe_CardError $e) {
            echo json_encode(array('status' => 500, 'error' => STRIPE_FAILED));
            exit();
        }
}
```

I try this code and is already. My problem is with webhook ie capture customer per month and checked if them account is expired or not